# What is the difference between $A^{-1}$ and $A^\Theta$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square invertible matrix. Then $$A \cdot A^{-1} = I$$.

Let $A^\Theta$ be the conjugate transpose matrix of $A$. Then $$A \cdot A^\Theta = I$$.

Both on multiplication  with $A$ gives $I$. So, what is the difference between them? They aren't same, I guess.

But, by applying cancellation law, $$ (A^{-1} \cdot A) A^{-1} = (A^{-1} \cdot A) A^\Theta \implies A^{-1} = A^\Theta$$. Is it wrong? If so, how?

Comment: A matrix $A$ does not "have" a unitary matrix, (like it may have an inverse). Rather being unitary is a property of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is an unitary matrix then it is invertible and its inverse is given by its conjugate transpose..

Comment: The operation you denote by $\Theta$ is not taking the "unitary" matrix of $A$, it is taking the complex conjugate. The definition of unitary (which is a property of a particular matrix as Seven mentioned above) is $A \cdot A^{\Theta} = I = A^{\Theta} \cdot A$. The complex conjugate is often denoted by $A^*$ or $A^\dagger$.

Comment: Just to be clear; for general matrices $A$, $AA^\Theta = I$ does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unitary matrix is one which $A^H = A^{-1}$, where $A^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose. Not all matrices are unitary, and unitary matrices are the complex analogues of orthogonal matrices (i.e. real matrices whose columns form an orthonormal basis).

Comment: Sir, what do you mean by $A^H$?

Comment: @user36790 $A^H$ means $A^\Theta$.